# / operand not working as expected in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-2.x

I'm reading the book [Tkinter GUI Application Development Hotshot](http://www.packtpub.com/tkinter-gui-application-development-hotshot/book) which is based on python 2, and I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *

rows = 5
un = 2
bp = 2
columns = un * bp
root = Tk()
right_frame = Frame(root)
right_frame.pack()
button = [[0 for x in range(columns)] for x in range(rows)]
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        active = False
        color = '#f3f3f3' if (j / bp) % 2 else '#9a72a9'
        button[i][j] = Button(right_frame, bg=color, relief='flat', width=1)
        button[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j)
root.mainloop()
```

and I have this result:
[image: img1]
but I need this:
[image: img2].

Tkinter works when I run it With Tkinter and python 2 but I get unexpected result when running it in python 3 and tkinter, what could cause this behaviour?

Comment: horribly broad title, btw.

Comment: what do you suggest I should put

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is likely due to how python 2.x and python 3.x handle the division operator. A lengthy description can be found here:

http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/

Comment: wow thanks That solved my problem I just changed (j / bp) to (j // bp)
and now its working

Answer (score 0):

for j in range (columns)
will generate 0, 1, 2, 3

j/bp gives a real result: 0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5 (AFAICT this is new in Python 3.0)

So (j/bp) % 2 gives: 0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5

Under Python 2.x, I think division of integers yielded an integer result:

j/bp gives 0, 0, 1, 1

(j/bp) % 2 gives 0,0,1,1

0 is interpreted as False, any other numeric as True

Hence the colour assignments you are seeing and the variation between Python 2.x and Python 3.x

Try using j//bp which gives the old (integer result) "floor division" in Python 3.x.

Comment: BTW nothing to do with TKinter!